# Couldn't disable dark mode in ios 13 - device specific permission alert based on plist permission text

Tags: ios, swift, xcode11.2.1, ios13.3

I have added in plist to disable dark mode for ios 13.

UserInterfaceStyle = .light

But still am getting dark mode is appearing for plist based on permission alert like , camera and touchid.

Please find the attachment of issue

[image]

How to disable dark mode for that alert also?

Comment: I don't think you can. That alert is related to iOS, not your app, right? How do you expect an app's plist to change something related to the OS?

Comment: yes. Am also thinking same. but this major issue right?

Comment: I don't think so, but YMMV. Look at this from a user's perspective: they'll know this is issues b the OS, not the app. You *still* have control over the alerts your app throws up (I think).

Answer (score 1):

This is an OS-level alert and therefore cannot be changed from the user's preferences.

Comment: Yes. Am thinking same. couldn't find anything